# BULK INSERT a xlsx file

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I have been struggling to import my `.xlsx` file for a while now and cant seem to figure out what is happening. I follow all the steps I find in other SO posts, and other tutorials.

I have a simple `.xlsx` file for now:

[image]

This is **the code** i run to grab the file and put it into a temp table for now:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Compare') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Compare;

CREATE TABLE #Compare
(
    Name VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,Lastname VARCHAR(MAX)
);


BULK INSERT #Compare
        FROM 'C:\Users\Michael\Documents\Taquanta\TAQKANBAN - 44 - 3pm Compare\compare.xlsx'
            WITH
    (
                FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
                ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
GO

SELECT * FROM #Compare c
```

And the results returned are not what i expected :(

**The results:**

[image]

Please could anyone let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: If this is one time activity, you could use import/export wizard in SSMS.

Comment: Unfortunately - i'm trying to build an automated insert and compare job. So I need to figure this out :)

Comment: Perhaps you need to go this way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124680/how-to-bulk-insert-from-xlsx-file-extension

Comment: @vnikhil - thanks for your help, but I just read that this is not even possible - i will have to try get the file in another format from the client! Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with PowerShell several times.  You could adapt something like the following.

```
$filename = "C:\Users\Michael\Documents\Taquanta\TAQKANBAN - 44 - 3pm Compare\compare.xlsx";
$ExcelConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='$filename';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
$ExcelConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($ExcelConnStr);
$ExcelConn.Open();
$ExcelCommand = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1`$a5:ae]" ,$ExcelConn);

$adpt = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter;
$adpt.SelectCommand = $ExcelCommand;

$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable;
[void]$adpt.Fill($dt);


$SQLConnStr = "Server=XXXXX;Database=XXXXX;Trusted_Connection=True;";
$SQLBulkCopy = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($SQLConnStr);
$SQLBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.TableName"
$SQLBulkCopy.WriteToServer($dt);
$SQLBulkCopy.Close();
```