# Excel database values to SQL Server and different tables

Tags: sql, database, excel, sql-server-2008, import

I got an Excel file with data which I want to import into a database in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express edition.

I do this with right click on a database -> task -> import data.

After this, my data from Excel is loaded in the database in one table.

But I want to seperate the columns from the Excel file into different tables.

So instead of loading all Excel data into one database and table, I want to load the Excel data into one database, but in different tables.

For example: Save column 1,2,3 from Excel in table A, and save column 4,5,6 from Excel in table B.

Anyone that knows how to do this?

Comment: Personally I would just import into a temporary table then write `INSERT INTO X SELECT` queries to move in the correct columns.

Comment: Did you look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375991/import-excel-spreadsheet-columns-into-sql-server-database

Comment: @ledbutter Need to re-install my r2 server and will look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the suggestion of @bendataclear:

"Personally I would just import into a temporary table then write INSERT INTO X SELECT queries to move in the correct columns."