# How to set IMEX=1 in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, odbc

I am using OS Windows 7 and Office 2010 and SQL Server 2008/2008R2/2012.
I am trying to import excel sheet to SQL Server. One column has several Numeric and Text values as well. While importing data from excel, numeric values are not getting imported. First row of excel sheet has headers. Many of the blogs have suggested to update IMEX=1. But I could not find how and where IMEX value has to be set to 1. Please help

Comment: set it in the connection string

Answer (score 1):

**try this pattern:**

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcelFile.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";
```

**Update**

For your additional question, please refer to this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/376017/1057667

It's already answered here I think.

Comment: Thanks. This works when I use Local instance of SQL Server as the excel file is in my local system. How to import excel which is in my local system and SQL Server instance is in other server. Also is it possible through SSMS Export-Import Wizard?