# Creating Table Variable and inserting 100,000 rows (how to bypass insert into 1000 records limit?)

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables, insert-into, table-variable

Creating Table Variable to insert into Temporary Table. But I need to repeat my insert into `@TableVariable VALUES` every 1000 records. How to bypass insert into 1000 records limit?

Current script is:

```
declare @@globalVariable Table (ID int, LName varchar (30), FName(30))
INSERT INTO @@globalVariable VALUES 
(1,'Johnson','John'),
...... row # 1001
INSERT INTO @@globalVariable VALUES 
(1001,'Polinski','Samuel'),
...... row # 2001
INSERT INTO @@globalVariable VALUES 
...... row # 3001
Select * Into #TempTable from INSERT INTO
```

I need to avoid repeating `[INSERT INTO @@globalVariable VALUES]` every thousand rows, as  my SSMS throws an error when not repeating it every 1000 rows.

Comment: Can you show us your existing script ? and what do you mean by `bypass insert into 1000 records limit` ?

Comment: Have you set the row limit in SSMS to 1000?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting more than 1000 rows from Excel into SQLServer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328730/inserting-more-than-1000-rows-from-excel-into-sqlserver)

Comment: Can you try something like the following? `INSERT INTO @@globalVariable SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 AS Id,'Johnson','John' UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS 2 As Id, 'LastName 2', 'FirstName 2' ...) T`. Also, what is the error provided by SSMS?

Comment: I would say, that suggested solution is not good when inserting thousands of records. So I think the only quick solution would be to build a formula in Excel to repeat  INSERT INTO @@globalVariable VALUES (1001,'Polinski','Samuel'), INSERT INTO @@globalVariable VALUES (1002,'Strader','Steward') for every set of values. So, this will eliminating 1000 rows limit...

Answer (score 0):

Union All is not a suggested solution when inserting thousands of records. So I think the only quick solution would be to build a formula in Excel to repeat

```
declare @@globalVariable Table (ID int, LName varchar (30), FName(30))
INSERT INTO @@globalVariable VALUES (1,'Johnson','John'),
INSERT INTO @@globalVariable VALUES (2,'Strader','Steward'),
INSERT INTO @@globalVariable VALUES (3,'Joany','Robert'),
...... row # 1001
INSERT INTO @@globalVariable VALUES (1001,'Polinski','Samuel'),

Select * Into #TempTable from INSERT INTO
```