# SQL Server Maximum rows that can be inserted in a single insert statment

Tags: sql-server

I want to do a batch insert, similar to this question

[How to do a batch insert in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql)

1. What is the limitation is SQL Server on how many rows can be inserted in a single insert statement ?
2. What happens when for example the first value is inserted but the second one causes a primary key violation. Are the all `INSERT` statements rolled back?

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b) 
VALUES (1, 2), (1, 3));
```

Comment: If you have to ask then you should probably be using BULK INSERT. I would think the answer to your question could be found with a Google search.

Comment: Yes I thought of that but , due to  certian restrictions in the system  BULK INSERT is not a valid option

Comment: `INSERT VALUES` limit is 1000, but it could be overriden with **[INSERT INTO SELECT FROM VALUES](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42703601/5070879)**, as for second question in SQL world vast majority of statements are all-or-nothing.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The Maximum number of rows you can insert in one statement is 1000 when using `INSERT INTO ... VALUES...` i.e.

```
INSERT INTO TableName( Colum1)
VALUES (1),
       (2),
       (3),...... upto 1000 rows.
```

But if your are using a SELECT statement to insert rows in a table, there is no limit for that, something like...

```
INSERT INTO TableName (ColName)
Select Col FROM AnotherTable
```

Now coming to your second question. What happens when an error occurs during an insert.

Well if you are inserting rows using multi-value construct

```
INSERT INTO TableName( Colum1)
VALUES (1),
       (2),
       (3)
```

In the above scenario if any row insert causes an error the whole statement will be rolled back and none of the rows will be inserted.

But if you were inserting rows with a separate statement for each row i.e. ...

```
INSERT INTO TableName( Colum1) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO TableName( Colum1) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO TableName( Colum1) VALUES (3)
```

In the above case each row insert is a separate statement and if any row insert caused an error only that specific insert statement will be rolled back the rest will be successfully inserted.

Comment: It would be nice if you included in the answer a link to documentation where this limitation of 1000 rows per `INSERT .. VALUES` is written: [Table Value Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)

Comment: ...and the error message, which is: "The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values."

Comment: Look at my answer below to see how you can easily add more than 1000 rows.

Comment: Any way to surpass that 1000 limit and make it to 100000 ?

Comment: Is there also a limit for updates and deletes? Or does this limit only apply to insertion?

Comment: @Ryker no there is no limit to updates or delete.

Answer (score 11):

Although the max is 1000, it's been demonstrated that performance begins to diminish at much smaller numbers. Eugene Philipov wrote a great article exploring this very topic:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/comparing-multiple-rows-insert-vs-single-row-insert-with-three-data-load-methods/

To summarize, the author did some very well-designed experimenting and found a sweet spot at around **25**. YMMV.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 11):

You can actually pass in an unlimited number of records using a subquery.

```
;WITH NewData AS (SELECT * FROM ( VALUES  (1, 'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C')) x (Id, SomeName))
INSERT INTO TableName (Column1, Column2) SELECT Id, SomeName FROM NewData
```

Comment: I used that syntax, it also works:
```INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table]
   (Column Names...) 
SELECT  ColumnNames... FROM  
(
VALUES (...),
(...),
(...),
(...),
) x (ColumnNames....)
```

Answer (score 4):

Dutchman's solution is cool, but it can be simplified. It turns out that you don't need the CTE. I tried it, and it works without the CTE, like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (Column1, Column2) SELECT Id, SomeName
  FROM  ( VALUES  (1, 'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C')) x (Id, SomeName)
```

Comment: As many already commented, this won't let you insert more than 1000 rows at a time....

Comment: @Dutchman, It does work. I've used it in production. As the accepted answer states, inserting the result of a SELECT will work around the 1000-row limitation. That's why your CTE-based answer works--not because of the CTE, but because you're SELECTing out of it. It turns out that you don't need the CTE; you can select the data directly as I have above and it still works around the limitation. So insert using > 1000 rows won't work, but inserting from a select as I have above will work. This is as simple as I've gotten it down, unless someone can simplify it further.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I add more than 1000 values to the temp table.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable(ID int)

INSERT INTO #TempTable (ID)
SELECT * from  (VALUES (45764),(45763),(45762),(45761),(45760),(45759),(45758),(45757),(45756)....)AS temp (column1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
with tempDataTable AS (SELECT *From (VALUES
(18001,79626,'1992-12-11','1993-12-11') -- this is data u want to insert
)x(empNO,sal,frmDate,toDate)) -- tempDataColoumns
INSERT INTO salaries(emp_no,salary,from_date,to_date) SELECT empNO,sal,frmDate,toDate from newData
```

Remove '--' at the time of query

Answer (score 0):

There's short workaround to avoid rows limit and still treat it like one statement (all goes in or if there's one error, everything is rolled back)

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b) 
SELECT 1,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,4 .......
```