# R: sqlAppendTable only works with numbers?

Tags: r, rsqlite, r-dbi

I am unable to get the R language DBI::sqlAppendTable function to work with anything other than numbers. Below is a bit of code illustrating the problem. I suspect the problem is that sqlAppendTable does not quote data. Any fix or workaround would be greatly appreciated.

```
num = data.frame(matrix(1:26, ncol=2))
let = data.frame(matrix(letters, ncol=2))

test.sqlAppendTable = function(dfr) {
    #dfr: A data frame.
    conx <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
    on.exit(dbDisconnect(conx))
    dbWriteTable(conx, "temp", dfr[1:5, ])
    temp = dbReadTable(conx, 'temp')
    print(temp)
    sat = sqlAppendTable(conx, 'temp', dfr[6:10, ])
    print(sat)
    rs = dbExecute(conx, sat)
    cat('Result set (rs): ')
    print(rs)
    temp = dbReadTable(conx, 'temp')
    print(temp)
}

test.sqlAppendTable(num) #Runs fine.
test.sqlAppendTable(let) #Generates error:
#Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : no such column: j
```

Comment: Why not use RSQLite's `dbWriteTable`, specifying *append* argument?

Comment: dbWriteTable with append sounds promising.

Comment: However, in the documentation of dbWriteTable I see no mention of append: http://127.0.0.1:31912/library/DBI/html/dbReadTable.html

Comment: Check official [CRAN docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/RSQLite.pdf) where *append* is an argument in `dbWriteTable` method.

Comment: @Parfait: You are right that dbWriteTable has an append option. But see my revised answer below: Writing a temporary table to the database, and inserting it into the target table, runs faster.

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this issue one too many times to not take a stab at writing my own work-around. Personally, I ran into this same issue with Microsoft SQL Server, but I figured this same solution would work for SQLite.  I'm working with:

- Database: Microsoft SQL Server hosted in Azure
- R: 3.5.0
- DBI: 1.0.0
- odbc: 1.1.6
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04

## Approach:

I wanted to avoid looping through rows for the sake of efficiency. I found that `mapply` and `paste0` could be combined in a more column-oriented fashion.

I'll admit it's a bit "hacky," but it's been working well for myself. **Use at  your own risk; I'm only using this for a small side project, not an enterprise solution.** Efficiency shouldn't be that big of an issue anyway, since there's a [1000 row limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471803/sql-server-maximum-rows-that-can-be-inserted-in-a-single-insert-statment) on inserts anyway.

## Replacement for "sqlAppendTable":

```
db_sql_append_table <- function(p_df, p_tbl) {
    # p_df: data.frame that contains the data to append/insert into the table
    # the names must be the same as those in the database
    # p_tbl: the name of the database table to insert/append into
    
    num_rows <- nrow(p_df)
    num_cols <- ncol(p_df)
    requires_quotes <- sapply(p_df, class) %in% c("character", "factor", "Date")
    commas <- rep(", ", num_rows)
    quotes <- rep("'", num_rows)
    
    str_columns <- ' ('
    column_names <- names(p_df)
    
    for(i in 1:num_cols) {
        if(i < num_cols) {
            str_columns <- paste0(str_columns, column_names[i], ", ")
        } else {
            str_columns <- paste0(str_columns, column_names[i], ") ")
        }
    }
    
    str_query <- paste0("INSERT INTO ", p_tbl, str_columns, "\nVALUES\n")   
    str_values <- rep("(", num_rows)
    
    for(i in 1:num_cols) {
        
        # not the last column; follow up with a comma
        if(i < num_cols) {
            if(requires_quotes[i]) {
                str_values <- mapply(paste0, str_values, quotes, p_df[[column_names[i]]], quotes, commas)        
            } else {
                str_values <- mapply(paste0, str_values, p_df[[column_names[i]]], commas)
            }
            
        # this is the last column; follow up with closing parenthesis
        } else {
            if(requires_quotes[i]) {
                str_values <- mapply(paste0, str_values, quotes, p_df[[column_names[i]]], quotes, ")")
            } else {
                str_values <- mapply(paste0, str_values, p_df[[column_names[i]]], ")")
            }
        }
    }
    
    # build out the query; collapse values with comma & newline; end with semicolon;
    str_values <- paste0(str_values, collapse=",\n")
    str_query <- paste0(str_query, str_values)
    str_query <- paste0(str_query, ";")
    return(str_query)
}
```

## Calling the function:

I wanted to keep this as similar to the original `sqlAppendTable` function as possible. This function only constructs the query.

You still have to wrap this function in a call to `dbExecute()` to actually insert/append rows to the database.

```
dbExecute(conn=conn, statement = db_sql_append_table(my_dataframe, "table_name"))
```

### EDIT

- Added "Date" as one of the types that needs to be quoted by this function as well. Thanks for that comment!

Comment: Great answer / workaround - cannot believe they still have not managed to get that INSERT working decently?! I noticed, and as future reference for anyone else having these issues, at least with MS SQL databases it also helps to add "Date" class to code line 3 ie `requires_quotes <- sapply(p_df, class) %in% c("character", "factor", "Date")`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a deficiency in the `RSQLite` package; values should be quoted indeed. Note that the quotes are added in the following example:

```r
DBI::sqlAppendTable(DBI::ANSI(), table = "test", data.frame(a = 1, b = "2"))
#> <SQL> INSERT INTO "test"
#>   ("a", "b")
#> VALUES
#>   (1, '2')
```

See also the corresponding [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstats-db/RSQLite/issues/207).

Comment: Thanks for raising this on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to cobble together a workaround:

1) Write the data frame that you want to append as a temporary table (temp) in the SQLite database file.

2) Append it to the target table (target) using the SQLite statement:

```
insert into target select * from temp;
```

3) Drop temp.

This runs quite fast, presumably thanks to SQLite being well optimized.

ADDENDUM:

You can indeed append a data frame to a database table using dbWriteTable, with the option append=TRUE. I have tested this against my workaround described above and, surprisingly, the workaround runs almost 40% faster than dbWriteTable.