# Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 1 (Date) error

Tags: sql-server, excel-2010, bulkinsert, temp-tables

I have an excel file that I want to `bulk insert` into `temp` table:

```
create table #tmptable
(
    Date varchar(10),
    Receipt varchar(50),
    Description varchar(100),
    [Card Member] varchar(50),
    [Account #] varchar(17),    
    Amount varchar(20)
)

bulk insert #tmptable
from 'C:\Transactions\example.xls'
with (FieldTerminator='\t', RowTerminator = '\n')
go
```

This is my excel file:

[image]

When executing `bulk` statement, getting the following error:

> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Bulk load data conversion error
>   (truncation) for row 1, column 1 (Date). Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid
>   character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (Date).

Do not know why it happens.

Comment: `#tmptable.[Date]` should be of `DATE` type and not `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Does not help. Have another similar error: "Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (Date)"

Comment: I think your bulk insert also reads the headers. Try adding `FirstRow= 2` on your `with` statement and follow @wewesthemenace 's advice on using `DATE ` type.

Comment: I added FirstRow=2, and getting another error: "Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (Date)."

Comment: I have to ask, did you also change the data type of `#tmptable.[Date]` to `DATE`? Just making sure.

Comment: Yes,  I did change it.

Comment: Well, can you post the actual .xls data? I mean not the one without images and formatting. Or is this the actual the content of the .xls file?

Comment: Yes, this is the content of the file

Comment: I think I've got it. See my answer.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375991/import-excel-spreadsheet-columns-into-sql-server-database

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are actually reading your headers, meaning the the data on the first few rows of your xls are images that's why you are getting a type mismatch error

[image]

get the row number of that first row where the data actually is.

then you use this:

```
create table #tmptable
(
    Date date,
    Receipt varchar(50),
    Description varchar(100),
    [Card Member] varchar(50),
    [Account #] varchar(17),    
    Amount varchar(20)
)

bulk insert #tmptable
from 'C:\Transactions\example.xls'
with (FieldTerminator='\t', RowTerminator = '\n', FirstRow = X)
go
```

where X is the row number where the data actually starts and not the headers

Comment: This is the only one file for now. Some files' first row might be different. These files are entered manually.

Comment: Well, you need to manually enter those first rows, bulkinsert will not skip over 'non-data' files. It will be up to you to determine which is the data and which is NOT the data. But for now this should get you through.

Comment: But how to determine when data starts. I tried to set `FirsRow = 8` since that's where data starts and I got "(0 row(s) affected)"

Comment: for excel 2010 and ssms 2012 its not working for me.. please give suggestions

Comment: If you really have lots of files like these, you better have another mecanism that reproduce all the files without headers, with datas starting right at first row, so you can work with them easely with your code. Just in case you haven't considered yet